# Distance between two points to throw negative values

Tags: javascript, rotation, distance

Im using the formula to calculate the distance between two points in order to determine how much to rotate an image when I move my mouse over it.

1. click, I capture the point where I clicked
2. mouse moves dragging, I record the location of the point where my mouse has moved to
3. I calculate the distance between origin and end
4. I rotate the image using this value which starts at 1.

So lets say I click on the center of the image, I start dragging my mouse to the right, my image rotates perfectly, then without letting go the click i drag back the mouse on my image, my image is now counter rotating, which is perfect. Now once the mouse reaches that center(where I clicked initially) it forces my image rotate in the oposite directions because the distance reached its limit(0) and the new values are all positive even though im moving to the left.

I understand that the distance between two points is supposed to be positive but I need something to make negative once it comes back to (0) so that I can rotate my image properly.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a simple jsFiddle example?

Comment: Are you using `atan2`? See this demo I did a while back: http://jsfiddle.net/wRexz/4/

Comment: Also, for drawing purposes, you should update your StartPoint on each draw, so that your EndPoint is relative to that. It greatly simplifies the process. If you need to see the AmountChanged when you release your mouse button, simply use a separate variable for it.

Comment: @Shmiddty Can you put this as the answer bellow. Your example definitely helped me achieve what I needed. I had to change a few things but the base is there. Just post it so I can select it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/wRexz/4/

```
var dragging = false, startpoint, endpoint, midpoint = $("#center").position();
midpoint = {x:midpoint.left - 2, y:midpoint.top-2};

$("#stage").mousedown(function(e){
    dragging = true;
    startpoint = {x:e.offsetX, y:e.offsetY};
});

$("#stage").mouseup(function(e){
    dragging = false;
});

$("#stage").mousemove(function(e){
    if (dragging){
        var angle = 0, sp = startpoint, mp = midpoint;
        var p = {x:e.offsetX, y:e.offsetY};
        var sAngle = Math.atan2((sp.y-mp.y),(sp.x - mp.x));
        var pAngle = Math.atan2((p.y-mp.y),(p.x - mp.x));        

        angle = (pAngle - sAngle) * 180/Math.PI;

        $("#display").text(angle);
        $('#rotateme').css({ rotate: '+=' + angle });

        startpoint = {x:p.x, y:p.y};
    }
});​
```

This will find the relative angle of rotation between two points. It updates each time the `mousemove` event is fired, so it will never be more than 180 degrees in one go (except when dragging around the midpoint). `Math.atan2` simplifies the logic compared to `Math.atan` as the latter isn't meant for a coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would be to use a simple `if` statement.

```
if (x2 < x1)
    dist = -dist;
```

You need to consider whether you want to rotate around the Y axis only, as I guess from what you write, or around the X axis too, in which case that rotation's direction will be governed by whether `(y2 < y1)` (composition of two rotations).